# Me da un dato erroneo al usar fscanf

Tags: array, c, string

Al usar fscanf para obtener los datos de unos marcajes (necesito separarlos para luego operar con ellos) me da un dato que no es el que quiero . Este es el codigo que tengo:

```
#include <string.h>

void main(){
    char A[100],nombre[100],apellidos[100];
    int hora[100],hora1[100],min[100],min1[100],i=0;

FILE *fichero;
fichero=fopen("Hola.txt","r");
    fscanf(fichero,"%i:%iE %i:%iS",&hora[0],&min[0],&hora1[0],&min1[0]);
    printf("%d",&hora[0]);


fclose(fichero);

}
```

Y este es el texto:

```
8:00E 14:45S 16:00E 17:00S
8:00E 14:45E 15:30E 17:00S
8:05E 14:45S 15:30E 17:00S
8:00E 14:45S 15:30E 16:45S 18:00E 20:00S
```

Comment: y qué dato es el que estás recibiendo?

Comment: En teoria deberia darme un 8, que es el primer numero de la primera fila , pero me da 6421... y no se porque esta mal

Comment: Eso es porque `printf` no debe recibir un puntero sino una copia del valor. `scanf` necesita punteros para poder modificar tus variables, pero `printf` no modifica nada, simplemente saca valores por la salida estándar. Te sobra el `&` en el `printf`